# dinamically require from db with node.js

Tags: node.js, express, require

I gota  mysql table in which are stored the available plugins for some users. I've written a function that mounts all the plugin routes and it goes like this (leaving error handling and file checking) :

```
var requireEnrolPlugins = function(app){
connection.query('Select name FROM ... where type = ?,[enrol],
(err,rows,fields) => {
async.eachOfSeries(rows,function(item,key,eachOfCallback){
require('path/to/plugin-dir/ ' + item.name + '/routes.js')(app);
eachOfCallback();
})
})
}
```

this function is called in a index.js file where all the routes are mounted, then the index.js file is declared in the app.js main file
If i try to require without the appEngine handler, it goes ok.
But if I add the (app) engine at the and of the require, it throws this error:

```
require(...) is not a function
at C:\Users\username\Desktop\node-
projects\project\functions\general_functions.js:70:33
at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:445:3)
```

Comment: Make sure you are not creating cyclic requires.

Comment: Is it the same if you assign a variable to it first? var route = require('path/to/plugin-dir/ ' + item.name + '/routes.js'); route(app); If its still the same error then try modifying the routes.js file with a module.exports = function(app){//Initialize app in here}

Comment: Please let me know if I need to expand this into an answer.. it should be fairly easy to do...

Comment: Yes, this was the problem ! in one of the required files I didn't wrap the routing with module.exports ! my fault, thank you !

Comment: FWIW, `require()` is synchronous, there's not need to use `async.eachOfSeries()` (a plain `forEach` will do)